# Existe alguma maneira de encurtar a declaração de propriedades?

Tags: vb.net, característica-linguagem, propriedade

Sei que no C# é possível fazer isso:

```
public string propriedade { get; set; }
```

Existe alguma forma curta de declarar propriedades com os procedimentos `Get` e `Set` no Visual Basic? A única forma que conheço é esta:

```
Private _propriedade As String
Public Property propriedade() As String
   Get
      Return _propriedade
   End Get
   Set(ByVal value As String)
       _propriedade = value
   End Set
End Property
```

Sei também que escrevendo `Property` e apertando <kbd>Tab</kbd>, o Visual Studio facilita o trabalho autocompletando com o nome escolhido para a propriedade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sintaxe deve usar a palavra-chave [`Property`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
Public Property Propriedade As String
```

Isso faz o mesmo que está na pergunta.

Ela pode ser inicializada, igual ao C#:

```
Public Property Propriedade As String = "Default"
```

Também pode usar um `ReadOnly`, mas teria que escrever o código da leitura, então não é tão prático quanto no C#:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Propriedade As String = "Default"
```

Ou `WriteOnly` (tem que escrever o código do `Set`):

```
Public WriteOnly Property Propriedade As String
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Property.vb).